# how to solve the problem in Linq to Object with type converting?

Tags: c#

I've tried to use Linq to Object. So I have 2 `ObservableCollections<T>`: `Items` and `ConstItems`. But Linq operation always returns an `IEnumerable` type. So I cant convert the type. How do I solve this problem?

```
TextChangedCommand = new Command(TextChanged);
private void TextChanged(object searchingText)
{
    string tempStr = searchingText as string;
    Items = ConstItems.Where(x=>x.Surname.ToLower().Contains(tempStr.ToLower()));
}
```

Comment: anytime you use `Where`, what you get is an IQueryable of the objects but if you execute the queryable this way `items.ToList()` you will have the objects as a list or `ToArray()` for an array

Comment: `Items = new ObservableCollections<MyClass>(ConstItems.Where(x=>x.Surname.ToLower().Contains(tempStr.ToLower()))`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code, screen images and scenario diagrams. To help you improve the content, title and tags of your query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: For example, what are `Command` and `ConstItems` ?

Comment: Don't use `.ToLower()` to perform case-insensitive string comparisons because it causes excessive string allocations and won't work with certain languages that have different casing rules. Instead use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Linq's `IEnumerable<T>`s are not "materialized" - you can materialize a Linq `IEnumerable<T>` by using a `To...` method like `ToList()` or `ToHashSet()` or `ToDictionary()`.

You can learn more about materialization here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/intermediate-materialization

BTW, your filter function can be improved - here's how I would do it:

(I assume `this.Items` is a `List<String>`).

```
private readonly Command textChangedCommand = new Command(TextChanged);

private void TextChanged(object searchingText)
{
    if( searchingText is String s )
    {
        this.Items = this.ConstItems
            .Where( x => x.Surname.IndexOf( s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) > -1 )
            .ToList()
    } 
}
```